# SwiftUI: Missing argument for parameter 'x' in call

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, parameters

My content view has a StateObject to a data model "Pilot."  The complier generates an error of "Missing argument for parameter 'pilot' in call.  Xcode offers the following fix: var pilot = Pilot(pilot: [Employee])... however, the complier generates a new error on that fix: "Cannot convert value of type '[Employee].Type' to expected argument type '[Employee]'"

Here is my Content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var pilot = Pilot(pilot: [Employee])

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            TabView {
                ProfileFormView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                        Text("Profile")
                    }
                EmployeeView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                    .padding()
            }
            .environmentObject(pilot)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my data model:

```
class Employee: Identifiable, Codable {
var id = UUID()
var age: Int
var yearGroup: Int
var category: String

init(age: Int, yearGroup: Int, category: String) {
    self.age = age
    self.yearGroup = yearGroup
    self.category = category
}
struct Data {
    var age: Int = 35
    var yearGroup: Int = 1
    var category: String = ""
}
var data: Data {
    Data(age: age, yearGroup: yearGroup, category: category)
}
}

@MainActor class Pilot: ObservableObject {
@Published var pilot: [Employee]

init(pilot: [Employee]) {
    self.pilot = pilot
}
}

class Data: Employee {
static let sampleData: [Employee] = [
    Employee(age: 35, yearGroup: 1, category: "B717")
]
}
```

I am also getting a similar compiler error in my Content view for the "Employee View()" which states: "Missing argument for parameter 'data' in call"

Here is my EmployeeView code:

```
struct EmployeeView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var pilot: Pilot

let data: [Employee]

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        List {
            ForEach(data) {line in
                EmployeeCardView(employee: line)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

/// UPDATE1 ///

I tried to pass an instance of Employee to Pilot but I've hit a new wall.  Here is my new code.

Here is my data model:

```
struct Employee: Identifiable, Codable {
var id = UUID()
var age: Int
var yearGroup: Int
var category: String

init(age: Int, yearGroup: Int, category: String) {
    self.age = age
    self.yearGroup = yearGroup
    self.category = category
}
struct UserInfo {
    var age: Int = 35
    var yearGroup: Int = 1
    var category: String = ""
}
var userInfo: UserInfo {
    UserInfo(age: age, yearGroup: yearGroup, category: category)
}
}

@MainActor class Pilot: ObservableObject {
@Published var pilot: [Employee]

init(pilot: [Employee]) {
    self.pilot = pilot
}

let pilotInfo = Employee(age: 35, yearGroup: 1, category: "B717")
}
```

And here is my Content view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var pilot = Pilot(pilotInfo) //<error here>
```

Now getting an error in the Content view: "Cannot find 'pilotInfo' in scope"

/// UPDATE 2 ///

I removed the UserInfo section of the model data and followed the guidance to take *one* Employee (not an array) and change the Content view variable.  That fixed those associated errors.

In an effort to comply with principles outlined in developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/displaying-data-in-a-list, I've tried to match the following from Apple's tutorial:

```
struct ScrumsView: View {
let scrums: [DailyScrum]

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(scrums, id: \.title) { scrum in
            CardView(scrum: scrum)
                .listRowBackground(scrum.theme.mainColor)
        }
    }
}
}
```

That's why my Employee view looks like this:

```
struct EmployeeView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var pilot: Pilot

let userInfo: [Pilot]

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        List {
            ForEach(userInfo, id: \.age) {line in  //ERRORs
                EmployeeCardView(employee: line)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The complier errors are:

1. Cannot convert value of type '[Pilot]' to expected argument type 'Binding'
2. Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred
3. Key path value type '*' cannot be converted to contextual type '*'

[image: Previous version model]
[image: Previous version View]
[image: Previous Version View Model]

///UPDATE 3///

```
struct ProfileFormView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var pilot: Pilot
@StateObject var vm: EmployeeViewModel = EmployeeViewModel()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Personal Information")) {
                DatePicker("Birthdate", selection: $vm.birthdate, displayedComponents: .date)
                DatePicker("New Hire Date", selection: $vm.newHireDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                Picker("Your Current Aircraft", selection: $vm.chosenAircraft) {
                    ForEach(vm.currentAircraft, id: \.self) {
                        Text ($0)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, my first attempt was much more complex but since I could not get my previous version views to take user input updates, I decided to start over with a more basic app to better learn the fundamentals of data management.

Comment: Lots of small issues here. 1) Don't name a class `Data` -- there's already a `Data` in Swift. 2) You have a class & a struct named `Data`. 3) Your `Employee` should probably be a `struct`. 4) You have to pass an *instance* of Employee to `Pilot`, not the type (thus the error). There's more, but that's a good place to start.

Comment: @jnpdx  Thank you for the quick feedback!  1&2) I've changed the names so I'm not using Data  3) I've made Employee a struct. 4) I think I correctly passed an instance of Employee to Pilot.  I added my updated code to the original post.  Now I'm getting a new error in the Content View: "Cannot find 'pilotInfo' in scope"

Comment: Yep -- not surprising. There's no variable called `pilotInfo` in that scope. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here. `Pilot` takes an array of `Employee` as a parameter (which is probably a mistake). It already *has* a parameter called `pilotInfo` (also probably a mistake). You probably want to change `Pilot` to take *one* `Employee` and then do `Pilot(pilot: Employee(age: 35, yearGroup: 1, category: "B717"))` or something like that.

Comment: Probably a good time to read a couple of Swift tutorials and get comfortable with the basics of the language.

Comment: @jnpdx. Thank you for your feedback and patience with inexperience.  I've read through the following language basics resources: 1. developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui, 2. docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide.  I've gone through the following tutorials once, some twice: 1. developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui, 2. CodeWithChris 14-day beginner challenge, 3. Many of Sean Allen's tutorials, 4. Many of Paul Hudson's tutorials, 5. Many of Swiftly Thinking tutorials.  I'll keep studying. The mistakes you noted are a result of mixing Apple tutorials w/ Paul Hudson EnvironmentObject videos.

Comment: @jnpdx I'm trying to create an app that a user can input their birthdate, hire date and some other data to project their yearly earnings.  I've been successful in creating a viewmodel that calculates annually increasing payrates which is displayed as a List in the View based on birthdate, hire date, etc. variables I've established.  However I have not been able to get the user-input data (via TextFields and Pickers) to update the variables.  So I've been doing my best to understand the basics of managing model data (apple dev tutorials, etc).

Comment: @jnpdx I truly appreciate your help, feedback and patience!

Comment: @jnpdx Your edits worked, thank you very much!  I've updated the original post with "Update 2" with the compiler errors in my Employee View.  I'm trying to apply the principles exactly from the apple developer tutorials for the Scrumdinger app, but I am missing something.

Comment: Where do you expect `userInfo` to be coming from? Are you *sure* it's going to be an array of `Pilot`? *And* you want a `Pilot` as an `EnvironmentObject` -- that doesn't sound right.

Comment: @jnpdx Being a novice at Swift, I'm not "sure" of just about anything.  But I did have a functioning app using an Array in a previous version only I couldn't get the data management piece right so the variables remained constant (unchanged by user input). I've added a portion of the view model and view to my original post so you can see why I think the Array method is a viable solution.

Comment: I expect my userInfo to be coming from my ProfileFormView (added in the original post as update 3).